# Checking a separability condition for Bochner measurability

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, operator-algebras

Equip $[0,\infty)$ with the Borel measure $\mu$. I am looking at an integral of the following form:

$$\int_0^\infty R(x)\,dx(\mu),$$

where $R:[0,\infty)\rightarrow B(H,K)$ is a continuous family of bounded linear operators between Hilbert spaces $H$ and $K$. Here $R(x) = (T+x)^{-1}$ is in fact a family of resolvent operators.

I understand that for this integral to make sense, the function $R$ first needs to be strongly $\mu$-measurable in the sense of Bochner integrals. By Pettis' Theorem, this means $R(x)$ needs to be $\mu$-almost-everywhere separably valued.

**Question:** Is it true that $R$ is $\mu$-almost-everywhere separably valued? That is, is the image of $R$ contained in a closed separable subspace of $B(H,K)$?

(Or maybe there are other tricks one can use to show measurability for functions taking values in $B(H,K)$, or perhaps non-separable $C^*$-algebras?)

Cheers!

Comment: Just a thought - perhaps this is related to the fact that the resolvent $R(x)$ can be expanded as a Neumann series, hence living in a separable subspace?

Comment: Your question seems to be: Is the linear hull of a separable set $S$ separable itself? - which is true. The dense set in $span(S)$ is the set of all finite linear combinations with rational coefficients of elements of the dense subset of $S$.

Comment: Actually, I wasn't sure that the set (which for me is the range of $R$) itself is separable.

Comment: That is the definition of the almost everywhere separably valued: there is a null set $N$ such that on $R( [0,\infty) \setminus N)$ is separable

Comment: Ah, I see my question needs to be worded better. I was trying to show that it was almost-everywhere separably valued. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

This may help;
Let $C$ be a measure space, $X$ a Banach space. 
A countably valued function $x: C\rightarrow X$ is Bochner Integrable
if the map $$a - \|x(a)\|$$ is Lebesgue measurable and the inverse image
under $x$ of each element in the range of $x$ is a measurable set in $C$.

A general function $x:C\rightarrow X$ is Bochner integrable if and only if there is a sequence $\{x(n)\}$ of countably valued Bochner integrable functions converging pointwise to $x$ in the following way;

1. $\|x(n)(a)->x(a)\|\rightarrow 0$ for almost all $a$
   and
2. $\lim \int \|x(a) - xn (a)\|\, dm = 0$

($m = $ Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$)